# Install Tor 0.4.x on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, repository, packaging, tor

We can install Tor 0.3.x on Ubuntu from Ubuntu's default repository.
I want to have updated tor version. Because the 0.3.x version doesn't work here any more.
Is there any repository that offers Tor 0.4.x for Ubuntu?
Or what is the standard way to compile 0.4.x or even better, as an Ubuntu package?

Comment: Why don't you use their [official repository](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en)?

Comment: Because the version in official repository is outdated and doesn't work as anti-filter any more

Comment: By 'Their' I mean torproject's repository not Ubuntu's repository, they got `0.4.x` in their repository, [here](https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/pool/main/t/tor/)!

Comment: @Ravexina Uh, Ok. But I can not open it. as it is also filtered here.

Comment: I have access to the unofficial repository on github.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to install tor are:

- You can install the torbrowser-launcher package wich gonna install tor in your home directory
- You can add this repository https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en (installation in the system)
- You can download the binary .tar.xz here https://www.torproject.org/download/

Comment: There are a couple of problems about these ways. 1 It's about tor browser and not tor. 2- The documentation you have posted is filtered here. 3- the tar.xz is not binary. It's archive (of source code) and needs to be compiled.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar You just have to extract the file `tar xvf *xz`